Deploy . Net core application to Azure Marketplace
We have the entire application hosted on azure which has various azure services which includes the .Net core app service, Sql server and many more.
Now we want to distribute this application as Azure Marketplace offer but I am not able to find any suitable resource on the net on how to package this application and go to Azure Marketplace.
I have seen many articles where you can setup the azure resources using ARM templates but I need to know if we can deploy the code also to the App service.
Thanks in advance.
I tried the deployment of resources using ARM templates and Azure Service Catalogue but not sure how to deploy the code.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
